How can I reconfigure my kitchen sink drain to eliminate one bowl?
My current sink has 2 drains. The right-hand drain runs down and towards the left drain. When they meet, it drops straight down into the P-trap and then runs back towards the wall.
I am planning on changing my sink to a single bowl sink, but the drain is on the right-hand side of the sink. I wanted to initially just add a 90 degree turn, but that would go straight into the dishwasher drain piece and that doesn't lock into the 90. Would I take an extension tube, cut the large end off and just use the small part in both the 90 and the dishwasher drain piece?


Could I use a 45 and put the dishwasher drain on the angle?

maybe just 15 or 30

Aside: The dishwasher drain loop should peak as high as possible in the cabinet to prevent water from flowing from the sink into the dishwasher. The part that is visible is completely below the bottom of both sinks.

Good Lord, you have a lot of slip joints and tailpieces.

Remove the tee and the straight slip-joint extension below it and replace with a waste elbow exactly like the horizontal elbow you already have (see arrow in pic) but turned vertically.


For the dishwasher you could simply replace the stacked tailpieces with a wye like this, from Oatey:


Isn't this what we already see immediately above the trap?

Not exactly.  You see a wye (really, a stubbed tailpiece) and straight tailpiece.
